# SPARQL RDFterm-equal FILTER

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I am trying to validate concepts such that their respective categories are related by a parent/child relation (`skos:broader`). Getting the resources and their categories is trivial but then something is going on when I try to filter them with the relation:

```
select distinct * 
where
  {

    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Model-checking>  dbo:wikiPageRedirect*   ?conceptChild             .
    ?conceptChild                                 dbo:wikiPageRedirects*  ?redirectedChild          .
    ?redirectedChild                              dct:subject             ?subjectChild             .
    ?subjectChild                                 skos:broader            ?broaderThanSubjectChild  .

    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Formal_methods>  dbo:wikiPageRedirect*   ?conceptParent            .
    ?conceptParent                                dbo:wikiPageRedirects*  ?redirectedParent         .
    ?redirectedParent                             dct:subject             ?subjectParent            .

    FILTER ( ?subjectParent  =  ?broaderThanSubjectChild )

  }
```

[This query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=select%20distinct%20*%20%0D%0Awhere%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FModel-checking%3E%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%20%20%3FconceptChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FconceptChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%20%3FredirectedChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FredirectedChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FsubjectChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FsubjectChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3Abroader%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FbroaderThanSubjectChild%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFormal_methods%3E%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%20%20%3FconceptParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FconceptParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%20%3FredirectedParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FredirectedParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FsubjectParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20(%20%3FsubjectParent%20%20%3D%20%20%3FbroaderThanSubjectChild%20)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) has [no results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20*%20%0D%0Awhere%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FModel-checking%3E%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%20%20%3FconceptChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FconceptChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%20%3FredirectedChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FredirectedChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FsubjectChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FsubjectChild%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20skos%3Abroader%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FbroaderThanSubjectChild%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFormal_methods%3E%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%20%20%3FconceptParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FconceptParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%20%3FredirectedParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FredirectedParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FsubjectParent%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%3FsubjectParent%20%20%3D%20%20%3FbroaderThanSubjectChild%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) (via the Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor on the public DBpedia endpoint) whereas the same [query without the filter](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=select%20distinct%20*%20where%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FModel-checking%3E%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%3FconceptChild.%20%20%0D%0A%3FconceptChild%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%3FredirectedChild.%0D%0A%3FredirectedChild%20dct%3Asubject%20%3FsubjectChild.%0D%0A%3FsubjectChild%20skos%3Abroader%20%3FbroaderThanSubjectChild.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFormal_methods%3E%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%3FconceptParent.%20%20%0D%0A%3FconceptParent%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%3FredirectedParent.%0D%0A%3FredirectedParent%20dct%3Asubject%20%3FsubjectParent.%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) produces [the expected results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20*%20where%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FModel-checking%3E%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%3FconceptChild.%20%20%0D%0A%3FconceptChild%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%3FredirectedChild.%0D%0A%3FredirectedChild%20dct%3Asubject%20%3FsubjectChild.%0D%0A%3FsubjectChild%20skos%3Abroader%20%3FbroaderThanSubjectChild.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFormal_methods%3E%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirect*%20%3FconceptParent.%20%20%0D%0A%3FconceptParent%20dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%3FredirectedParent.%0D%0A%3FredirectedParent%20dct%3Asubject%20%3FsubjectParent.%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Virtuoso to me.

Comment: If you haven't already, I strongly encourage reporting this issue (which does appear to be a bug) directly to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [Virtuoso Open Source project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), or the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php).

Comment: I was going to report it now but it looks like the results changed. Now, the results of the query without the filter are also empty.

Answer (score 0):

This does look like some kind of bug.  Interestingly, if you replace the **filter** with a **bind**, e.g.,

bind((?subjectParent = ?broaderThanSubjectChild) as ?TEST)

you'll get 1 in one row, and 0 in the rest, so the comparison seems to be happening, but the **filter** is breaking for some reason.